# Header divider doesn't display properly after approving suggested edits

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, suggested-edits, header

After suggested edits are approved, the big colored block containing the number of pending edits in the queue disappears. For most users, this is not a problem. For the user who reviewed the edits, though, the block leaves behind one of the dividers that separated it from other elements in the header bar. As a result, the user sees two dividers with nothing between them but empty space.

[image: empty suggested edits tab with consecutive dividers in header]

The empty space in the header doesn't go away until a new page is loaded. I know, I know, it's minor, I'm not arguing that, but still.

Comment: Apparently, the opposite problem exists for the block containing the number of flags in chat: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79238/chat-header-lacks-divider-between-username-and-flags

Comment: I thought the bug about "you approve an edit and the counter stays the same" was trivial and unimportant, but this takes it to a whole new level

Comment: I try, @Michael. I actually noticed this a while ago and held off on reporting it because it's not too significant, but something really bugs me about that empty space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be fixed in the next build, it was an issue with suggested edits on sites with a 0 threshold (e.g. even 1 suggested edit will appear in the header).

Things appear a bit different for moderator vs non-moderator users, so we weren't readily seeing the issue here, but it'll be fixed in a build tonight.

Comment: I've still got double bars between `tools` and `chat` here on MSO and MSU.

Comment: @ChrisF - Ok it's *really* fixed in the next build, I see what was happening now, it appears differently for moderators which was throwing things off, it's fixed for sites with a 0 suggested edit threshold now - we'll be deploying sometime today.

Comment: @ChrisF - We deployed for other reasons ahead of schedule, you should see this fixed now.

Comment: Yep - Double bar has now gone.

Answer (score 1):

*bumping*

It looks like this has regressed (backgressed?) to the point where the double divider shows up all the time, even when there weren't any suggested edits to begin with.

[image: double divider]

I took this screenshot right after I refreshed the page, and I can consistently reproduce on every MSO page I visit.

Comment: Hmm, I'm seeing it now on all sites I have accounts for (SO, meta.SO, SU, meta.SU, etc.)  The empty spot is sitting to the left of the chat link too.  It wasn't like that when I initially saw this.  I only noticed it about an hour ago from now.  I've never seen anything else new up in that spot.  I figured it was a 10k+ thing.  But I don't have it anywhere so far.

Comment: Wait a minute... I didn't realize this until now but in my case, [the logout link is missing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80610/logout-link-now-missing).  It doesn't seem like you have the same problem.

Comment: +1, I was about to update the question with this

Comment: Possibly the same as this bug: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80640/logout-link-was-moved-to-my-profile-but-vertical-line-is-there-is-it-issue