# Logout link was moved to my profile, but vertical line '|' is there? Is it issue?

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, meta

Is it a small issue?:
[image]

But seems the following looks much better ;):
[image]

Comment: I see this on Server Fault (where I don't have the `tools` menu) but not on Stack Overflow (where I do). I also see it here on MSO and MSF and MSU where it appears between tools and chat.

Comment: Leave Broken-ey Space alone!

Comment: It's gone for me on SF & MSF, but still there on MSU and MSO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is now fixed; sorry about that.

Comment: Jeff, do you mind taking a look at a [similar bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79307/header-divider-doesnt-display-properly-after-approving-suggested-edits/80586#80586)? Not the one in the question (well, that'd be nice too), but the one in my pseudo-answer is almost identical.